# More layers and performance issue

Tags: c#, performance, architecture

Based on [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tlMTJDKiug) presentation(for more detail) it seems that having unduly layers and assembly could cause performance problem. take a look at this scenario , it's about sending a message on "Contact Us" part of an application:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ContactViewModel contactViewModel)
{
    var request = new CreateContactRequest(contactViewModel);
    _contactService.CreateContact(request);
    return View();
}
```

it is just a MVC controller action to create the contact by request response pattern, now about the service method imp  in Service layer I have this piece of code:

```
public CreateContactResponse CreateContact(CreateContactRequest request)
{
    var response = new CreateContactResponse();
    var contact = request.ContactViewModel.ConvertToContactModel();
    try
    {
        _contactRepository.Add(contact);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
        response.Success = true;
        response.MessageType = MessageType.Success;
        response.Message = ServiceMessages.GeneralServiceSuccessMessageOnCreation;
        _logger.Log(response.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.MessageType = MessageType.UnSuccess;
        response.Message = ServiceMessages.GeneralServiceErrorMessageOnCreation;
        _logger.Error(exception.Message);
    }
    return response;
}
```

service methods converts the view model to model by an extension method and it calls the below method of nHibernate to persist in data base in repository layer:

```
public void Add(T entity)
{
    SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Save(entity);
}
```

and finally after committing by UnitOfWork pattern, it persists in database. I really reduced the amount of code and all the process of creating this simple contact in Database. this code implementation has been done in Domain Driven Design and it's patterns. it obviously is more readable and maintainable and extendable for every changes, but I can also write something like this for creating the contact:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Contact contact)
{
    SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().Save(contact);
    return View();
}
```

in this kind of implementation, there is no need to go throw five layers to persist a contact, yeah!?
I know for creating a contact and this kind of simple business the second imp is the best but for complex businesses it's impossible to have an action to handle everything. definitely calling A by B and B by C and ... is makes a kind of performance issue.

Now I'm just wanna to know that what is the ways of optimizing the layered architecture performance?

Comment: calling methods can never cause a performance issue. If you `do` have a performance issue, you need to identify where the bottleneck is exactly happening. If you don't, forget all that. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: then you can see the presentation I liked above to see the sample.

Comment: @HighCore That's not true. If calling methods didn't come with a cost there would be no reason to inline calls. I can't say if the invocation is the problem in the question, but your claim that "calling methods can never cause a performance issue" is simply not true.

Comment: sure the second method imp is in one assembly and definitely faster than having lot's of different assemblies. you can test it

Comment: there is a good discussion in http://forums.asp.net/t/1591736.aspx
 and also in http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_three_tier_and_n-tier_architecture?#slide=4 but not the best answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blogged a post about it, although it's not the easy to optimize n-layered architectures but I've talked about some tips:
http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/115/disadvantages-of-n-layered-architectures